problem with Bitcoin core
The coins were sent from the exchange since yesterday but they did not arrive at Bitcoin Core Hash: 6d580fac9e6597016461e43a9a29d1bf627bcada54efd016d4e0b8fa307f9bf9


Your payment was confirmed yesterday. Your Bitcoin Core is not synchronized with the network, yet. You will see the payment in Bitcoin Core, when it finished synchronizing.

Thank you, thank you. I hope it does not close until the wait is confirmed
